# 403 Forbidden - Cannot be Resolved, Searched High and Low

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, centos

I've been working on this error for over 4 hours now, and every result on "site:stackoverflow.com" is purple on my google, I've tried all suggestions and it does not work. Finally, I reinstalled all the LAMP stack services, and to no avail it's still not working. If anyone would be willing to troubleshoot this for me, I would much appreciate it (I am still a Linux newb).

**vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf**

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip <workstationip>
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from <workstationip>
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I have also tried to do:

```
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Allow from all
   </IfModule>
```

I have also ensured 'setenforce 0' and still nothing.

My httpd log states "server configuration" blocked my access to /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Still goes unsolved. I've now tried 'chmod 755' and 'chmod 777' and 'chgrp' and 'chown' to the /usr/share/phpMyAdmin folder and no result

Comment: Ensured that
`<directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin">
    Require all granted
</directory>`
is set as well, still doesn't work.

Did a complete reboot, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to it after dinner and it worked. My guess is the DNS update fixed it.